# Laravel 5 and Mockery, doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mockery

I've been debugging line per line and it seems the error comes when I try to bind a repository to a mock:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('MyNamespace\Repositories\MyModelInterfaceRepository');

// Error is in this line
$this->app->instance('MyNamespace\Repositories\MyModelInterfaceRepository', $mock);
```

I already bound repo interface and implementation and it works on the browser, **it only fails in the test case, giving me an error 500**.

My controller's constructor goes like this:

```
use MyNamespace\Repositories\MyModelInterfaceRepository;

class MyController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(MyModelInterfaceRepository $repo) {
        $this->repo = $repo;
    }
....
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

[Here is the log](http://pastebin.com/zLnEASpu). It seems to be something about the View not receiving a proper `foreach` argument, which is possibly caused because the mock call is returning `null`.

For anyone who also encounters this problem, in this case, should the controller validate if the returned value is null (considering Eloquent would return an empty array if no records, but never null), or should the `Mockery` make sure it returns a value?

Comment: take a look at laravel log ``storage/logs/laravel.log`` and copy-paste error message from it.

Comment: Mock was returning null, so view crashed. Thanks for this, I'm new to Laravel so I didn't know yet that logs where kept there.

Comment: go forward and check variable you're passing into foreach in ``magazines/index.blade.php``. You can do it by using ``{{ dd($var) }}`` in blade view.

Comment: yeah, they are indeed null. I was following a tutorial and the guy only mocked the repo, not the object returned. So I guess I know have to mock the returned objects so that views wont crash... can eloquent models be mocked?

Comment: If you're trying to isolate a controller method, then you can also mock the view with something like: `View::shouldReceive('make')->once()->with('some-view-name', array('results' => 'some response from repository'))->andReturn('compiled view');` Then you can assert that your `controller->method()` returns `compiled view`. If you provide your test and controller method, I could provide more detail.